# Problema al abrir mi proyecto que guardé en github

Tags: java, android

Guardé el proyecto el día anterior y ahora cuando voy a ejecutar la app me sale este error y aun no logro identificar donde se encuentra:

> Error while executing: am start -n
>   "com.example.usuario.app.myroodent/com.example.usuario.app.myroodent.SplActivity"
>   -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
>       Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]
>   cmp=com.example.usuario.app.myroodent/.SplActivity }
>       Error type 3
>       Error: Activity class {com.example.usuario.app.myroodent/com.example.usuario.app.myroodent.SplActivity}
>   does not exist. Error while Launching activity

Este es el Manifest

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Andres, no se agrego el Manifest.xml, pero revisa que el nombre de la Activity es correcto así como la ruta donde se encuentra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error es básicamente que no existe la Activity llamada "SplActivity"  la cual declaraste como "launcher":

```
    <activity
        android:name=".SplActivity"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        ...
     </activity>
```

Asegura:

1) que la ruta donde se encuentra la clase sea:

```
/app/src/com/example/usuario/app/myroodent/
```

ya que el paquete indicado es:

```
com.example.usuario.app.myroodent
```

2) que el archivo de la clase se llamé en realidad `SplActivity.java`

Comment: ya actualice el post con imagen no pude subir el manifest completo creo q se alcanza a ver

Comment: Disculpen el error era que el dispositivo donde lo estaba ejecutando no tenia espacio    -_-